# Will Daredevil be serialized or dump released?

Tags: production, marvel-cinematic-universe, distribution, daredevil-tv

*[Daredevil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_%28TV_series%29)* is going to be released on VOD, specifically Netflix which typically sticks to a model of releasing all episodes simultaneously, like a box set, to encourage its connection with 'Binge watching'...

However, it previously had the rights to *Breaking Bad* and instead released an episode a week, to great success (although this wasn't by choice: ABC controlled the first broadcast and thus Netflix could only broadcast episodes simultaneously...

Given that *Daredevil* is a comic book, which typically thrive on episodic/cliff hanger narratives (even when remediated into television), **do we know under which strategy *Daredevil* and *The Defenders* will be released?**

Different sources make differing claims: the Wiki page states it will be dump released onto Netflix, but the source it cites for this claim is actually Jeph Loeb [refusing to comment either way](http://www.hitfix.com/news/marvel-tv-head-daredevil-starts-shooting-in-july-jessica-jones-next-up)...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is simply a yes or no question.

Comment: @Leatherwing *"because it is simply a yes or no question."* - WUT? How's that make it off-topic?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I was following this meta discussion, and may have included rules from other sites in my opinion. Fortunately, I don't have the capability to decide unilaterally for the site. I merely offered my opinion. But I will retract the close vote.   http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/520/questions-about-the-current-state-of-a-tv-series

Comment: @Leatherwing Ok, then it seem you just phrased your close-reason way too confusingly if that was the actual point you wanted to make.

Answer (score 3):

It *seems* likely that they will be made available for binge watching.

I'm basing this on a quote from Marvel Entertainment's Chief Creative Officer, Joe Quesada, [who stated](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=52717):

> "One of the advantages is really from the planning stage -- obviously
>   it's much easier to work with a smaller number of episodes than it is
>   with a larger number of episodes. We can sit there and look at 13
>   episodes and plan it out as a very large movie. It makes seeing the
>   bigger picture a little bit easier. ***You can't deny that there will be
>   binge-viewing. You know that there are going to be some Marvel fans
>   that when this show premieres, they are going to go on to Netflix, and
>   they are going to sit there for 12 to 13-plus hours, and watch the
>   entire thing all the way through...*** Even the way that you parse out
>   information and reveals within the show can be different than you
>   would on weekly TV. With weekly TV, you sit there and go, "The
>   audience may not want to wait two or three weeks to get this
>   particular bit of information." Whereas with Netflix, we might be able
>   to hold onto a particular piece of information, because they may just
>   watch it two hours later."

This article was from seven months ago, which would be roughly May 2014. Although it likely took a few weeks for the article to go to live, given that it is a full two months *after* the quotes from Jeph Loeb you provided I think it's probably the most recent piece of information we have.

Ultimately, it does appear that Daredevil will be released for binge watching, given Quesada's comments, but this could of course be subject to change.

Comment: Thanks Martin, although Jeph Loeb is actually head of Marvel Television (and Quesada, being head of Comics, has no swing in the transmedia board), so I'll wait and see if anyone who's more involved in the TV universe has commented before marking correct.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Is the dump-release having actually happened sufficient commentary to consider closing this file (i.e. accepting and asnwer or posting another one)? ;-)